# SOQL Query for Unchanged fields

Tags: soql

I want to query records where a field value remain unchanged in an year.
For Example query all accounts where status field was not changed in 2020.

If I query account history it will give me all the records for changed value in the field.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do a join on history tables. So this ask is pretty simple.

```
SELECT ...
FROM Account
WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT AccountId
    FROM AccountHistory
    WHERE Field = 'Status'
    AND CreatedDate = LAST_YEAR
)
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, 

I thought of doing so but here is the catch

For example :

An account was in 'Active' status in 2020 and it became inactive in 2021.
Now such accounts should show up in my list but when I add Status = Active in my query the record won't be pulled.

I have exported all records for now and doing analysis in excel. 
Thanks for your inputs.